# Звуковая и видео дорожка по отдельности

Tags: javascript, видео, webp, mp4

На сколько я знаю, ютуб. Хранить видео в двух форматах: mp4 и webp, а звуковую дорожку отдельно.

Интересно, поскольку видеофайлов много в разном качестве и в разных форматах, а звуковая дорожка одна. Получается что таким образом ютуб эконом место на диске, за счет одной вуковой дорожки, а не создает под каждое качество видео.

Собственно это так? Как в таком случаи проигрывается видео, получается что необходимо видео и звук запускать одновременно? а при перемотке корректировать там и там?

Comment: У элементов `audio` и `video` можно узнать текущее время.

Comment: Это так. Именно так ютуб проигрывает видео, отдельно картинку, отдельно видео?

Answer (score 0):

У элементов **audio** и **video** есть общее свойство **currentTime**. Именно оно не позволяет сопоставляться изображению со звуком в разнобой. Если видео запускается не сначала, указывается одно и то же стартовое **currentTime**:

```
video.currentTime = audio.currentTime = range.value ;   
video.play();
audio.play();
```

Comment: Ютуб проигрывает видео с таким подходом. Отдельно проигрывает картинку, отдельно аудио?

Comment: Типа да, но точно не знаю. Раньше проигрывал **flash**.

Comment: Получается что ютуб меняет только картинку, а звуковая дорожка одна на все расширения(качества)

Comment: Вообще, звуковые данные намного меньше объёмом, чем данные изображения, так что, может и для каждого варианта качества идёт свой звук, чтобы не нужно было раздельно сопрягать.